# Virtual generators

Tags: ct.category-theory

Let $\mathcal{K}$ be a category.

**Prop 1.** If $\mathcal{K}$ has a (strong) generator then there is a faithful (and conservative) functor $U: \mathcal{K} \to \text{Set}$ preserving connected limits.

**Def 2.** *A virtual (strong) generator* on $\mathcal{K}$ is a  a faithful (and conservative) functor $U: \mathcal{K} \to \text{Set}$ preserving connected limits.

Generators are a useful notion, and even more important, it occurs quite often that a category of interest has a generator. In my research, sometimes I study the properties of those categories having a faithful functor to set, that's how I came up with this definition.

> **Q1.** Is there any known example of a category with a virtual generator which has no real generator?
>
> **Q2.** How well behaved is the notion of  virtual generator? To answer this question, do you have any testing lemma?

For example, I was thinking about the following.

**Prop 3.** Let $L: \mathcal{K} \rightleftarrows \mathcal{C}: R$ be an adjunction where $R$ is faithful (conservative). Then if $\mathcal{K}$ has a (strong) generator, also $\mathcal{C}$ has a (strong) generator.

It is very easy to prove the analogous of this theorem for virtual generators. In fact, it is essentially trivial.

---

I would like to give a better justification of my definition with the following Proposition.

**Prop 4.** Let $\mathcal{K}$ be a complete category. Then the following are equivalent:

- $\mathcal{K}$ has a generator.
- $\mathcal{K}$ has a virtual generator verifying the solution set condition.
- $\mathcal{K}$ has a virtual generator that is a small functor.

Comment: I guess I would tend to think that one of the main reasons to have a generator around is to apply the adjoint functor theorem, but in order to do that I think your generator has to be actual rather than virtual. Maybe you can get a "virtual adjoint functor" though...